# Why does the num.is_integer() function returns false

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop

```
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8 # The pay after %20 discount
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        #Run validations to the recieved arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal tozero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater than or equal to zero!"

        # Assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

        #Actions to execute

        Item.all.append(self)


    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)
        for item in items:
        Item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=float(item.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item.get('quantity')),
            )
    @staticmethod
    def is_integer(num):
        #We will count out the floats that are .0
        if isinstance(num, float):
            #Count out the floats that are point zero
            return num.is_integer()
        elif isinstance(num, int):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item('{self.name}', {self.price}, {self.quantity})"
```

Im currently learning python and trying to understand the OOP Concept.I understood it all except the following lines

```
def is_integer(num):
    #We will count out the floats that are .0
    if isinstance(num, float):
        #Count out the floats that are point zero
        return num.is_integer()
    elif isinstance(num, int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can someone explain me why num.is_integer() returns False?
That function is defined for the purpose of removing .0 from floats like 100.0 or 50.0 (Tutorial says that)

It's my firs time encountering this type of return usage.I'm accustomed to return a*b or return 'Hi' type of stuff.

Comment: that method is for checking if something is an integer or not... that's it, if it is considered an integer, it returns `True`, else it returns `False`, also that `else:` is not necessary, can just unindent `return False` and remove `else:`

Comment: Just a matter of opinion but I think the is_integer() function is a misnomer. For example: *(1.0).is_integer() == True* but it's not an integer at all. It's a float with no significant decimal places

Answer (score 0):

If your is_integer() function is returning False it's because you're either passing a float that has a significant fractional part or some object that is neither int nor float.

You might find this change to that function useful:

```
def is_integer(n):
    if __debug__:
        print(type(n))
    return n.is_integer() if isinstance(n, float) else isinstance(n, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is nothing unusual about this type of return. To use your examples:

1. `return 'Hi'` - returns the string 'Hi' back
2. `return a * b` - say a=3, b=5, it calculates a*b and returns the result, 15
3. `return num.is_integer()` - this will check if the number is an integer or not and returns the result, True or False

One note on [is_integer()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html), it will say both `50` and `50.0` are integers even though strictly speaking, `50` is a **int datatype** and `50.0` is a **float datatype** in Python. If you go through the below code with this knowledge then it seems it does the same thing except that you would call it with `Item.is_integer(50)`.

```py
def is_integer(num):
    #We will count out the floats that are .0
    if isinstance(num, float):
        #Count out the floats that are point zero
        return num.is_integer()
    elif isinstance(num, int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same tutorial and I actually came here to understand the same thing. From what I have looked up, there is some confusion here because of the way its written in the tutorial. To beginners like us, this looks like a recursive function and the whole thing seems to be in a loop when it actually isn't and is_integer() is a pre-defined function (link for documentation: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html)

A better way to write this, in my opinion, would be to define your function as check_integer or something else so there won't be any ambiguity. Here's how I did it:

```
@staticmethod
def check_int(num): #this is better than using "def is_integer(num)"
    #we will count out the floats that end with .0 e.g 5.0,10.0 etc.
    if isinstance(num,float):
        #count out floats with point zero
        return num.is_integer()
    if isinstance(num,int):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll do my research more in depth for my later codes.

Answer (score 0):

> Just needs to remember that functions with same name and different
> parameter's are different

In our case

```
is_integer(num): user-defined function #which is defined by us
is_integer(): inbuilt function #which is used inside the function
```

I am also following same tutorial in freecodecamp youtube channel, Object oriented programming using python https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej_02ICOIgs&t=968s

At 1:09:00 timestamp i faced similar confusion so i ran it is separately and understood it, we are not removing any .0 from num and we are using recursion.

the .is_integer() function used inside without parameter is inbuilt function [enter link description here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html)

so that inbuilt function generally removes .0 presence and return true for integers and false for point values. i have checked with several inputs for better understanding

for integers
[image: check for int]

Check for float
[image: check for float]

check for int that looks like 12.0
[image: check for point int]

Comment: Please do not post source code as image. It is hard to interpret and adopt.

Comment: The code is available in the question itself, I am just showing the respective output fr the code changes